# Child tabs under respective parent tab is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On clicking on Tab2, it is showing `<div id="custom-sub-tab0"` and on click on Tab3, it is not displaying anything. On click on Tab3, it should display `<div id="custom-sub-tab0"`

html:

```
<nav class="ti_tabs u-clear">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#std-sub-tab0"> <span> Tab1 </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> <span> Tab2 </span></a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#custom-sub-tab0"> <span> Tab3 </span></a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
        <div id="std-sub-tab0" class="ti_subTabNav" data-nav="sub-tab">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="/subtab0.html"><span> Featured applications </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/content/ti/en_US/amplifiers/overview/reference-designs.html"><span> Reference designs </span></a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div id="custom-sub-tab0" class="ti_subTabNav" data-nav="sub-tab">
            <ul>
                    <li class="is-active"><a href="custtab0.html"><span> customsubtab1 </span></a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

my juery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("div[id*=sub-tab]").hide();
        $("div[id*=sub-tab]").find("ul > li.is-active").parent().parent('div').show();
        $('.ti_tabs ul li').click(function(){
                $('.ti_tabs ul li').removeClass('is-active');
                $(this).addClass('is-active');
                $('div[id*=sub-tab]').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
            });
    });
```

I tried many things but its still not working. I am new to jquery. Please guide.

Comment: Provide html code.

Comment: @Kinduser edited to include html.

Comment: please specify your problem correctly.

Comment: you have only 2 sub-tabs, and 3 li to click, so for Tab3 the index would be 2, and it wont find any sub-tabs

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/81rfae3f/

Answer (score 0):

You only have two elements with id*=sub-tab, so index == 2 will not shown anything.

Here's how you might want to edit your JS to work (possibly) the way you wanted it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[id*=sub-tab] li").hide();
    $("div[id*=sub-tab] li").first().show();
    $("div[id*=sub-tab]").find("ul > li.is-active").parent().parent('div').show();
    $('.ti_tabs ul li').click(function(){
        $('.ti_tabs ul li').removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
        var items = $('div[id*=sub-tab] ul li');
        items.hide();
        $(items[$(this).index()]).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only 2 sub-tabs and 3 LIs, so there will be an index mismatch.